# ¿Por qué hay veces que aunque modifique alguna variable del código original, al ejecutarlo utiliza las variables de la versión original?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Supongamos que tengo un código en el cual tengo una variable `a = 3`. Lo ejecuto y obtengo un resultado. A continuación quiero ejecutar de nuevo el mismo código pero cambiando el valor de esa variable haciendo por ejemplo `a = 7`. Lo ejecuto de nuevo y resulta que obtengo el mismo resultado que con `a = 3`(y no es porque el resultado sea el mismo en ambos casos).

Es algo que me sucede de vez en cuando y pierdo tiempo hasta que me doy cuenta de que no "reconoce" el cambio realizado a pesar de haber salvado el archivo antes de ejecutarlo. Sin embargo si reinicio el entorno (Spyder 3), se soluciona mi problema.

¿Por qué puede ser que suceda esto?

Comment: Suele funcionarme con 'reset' en el comand window Intenta con ese comando Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las variables no son borradas antes de cada ejecución.

Para que las variables sean borradas antes de cada ejecución hay que ir a:

> Herramientas > Preferencias > Ejecutar

Apartado:

> Ajustes generales

Y seleccionar la casilla:

> Borrar todas las variables antes de la ejecución.

---

Si por algún motivo no quieres que sea una preferencia de ejecución general, si no que se aplique tan sólo a un archivo en concreto, se puede modificar la "Configuración de ejecución por archivo":

> Ejecutar > Configuración por archivo

Apartado:

> Ajustes generales

Y seleccionar la casilla:

> Borrar todas las variables antes de la ejecución.

Answer (score 1):

Nunca he trabajado con ese entorno, sin embargo creo que hay que limpiar las variables por algo que tiene habilitado ese entorno. Mira [este enlace](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/2563), talvez te pueda servir.

Comment: He encontrado la solución en el enlace. Voy a autoresponderme.